# I'm trying to run my first program on Java using the Elipse IDE and this is the error that I'm getting

Tags: eclipse

Description Resource Path Location Type
Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module 'MyFirstProgram'Main.java/MyFirstProgram/srcline 1Java Problem

I was trying to create a class for my code

Answer (score 0):

With a `module-info.java` file you use the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), which does not allow to have other code in the default package.

**Delete your `module-info.java` file** (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project folder and choosing *Configure*) or move your code into a package so that `module-info.java` is the only Java file in the default package.